# Solr - calculate duration from start and end dates

Tags: solr, solrcloud

Using Solr 8.0.0, with each document holding a start timestamp field and an end timestamp field, how would I query in a way that returns just the duration between these dates? So I would be going for an equation like this:

(Endtime - Starttime) - 500 seconds = 23 seconds over expected duration.

But getting the result across all documents in the collection.

Would this be the subject of a streaming expression? Any example code you can give? I specifically want to keep this calculation load within the SolrCloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [use a function query](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/function-queries.html). The [`ms` function](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/function-queries.html#ms-function) gives you the difference in milliseconds between two dates. You can [use `sub` to subtract 500 seconds](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/function-queries.html) from that number.

You can use [the `frange` query parser](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/other-parsers.html#OtherParsers-FunctionRangeQueryParser) to filter documents that match a given range. Which means we end up with something like:

```
q={!frange l=0}sub(ms(endtime,starttime),500000)
```

Comment: You are a life saver! I don't know why I was stuck on trying streaming expressions. For the record, this doesn't work in q=, but does work in fl=

Comment: When used in `q` it will be used to filter the documents, while when used in `fl` the value will be returned. You can also use `_val_:sub(...)` to use the calculated value as the score of each document.